# Как проверить наличие интернет соединения?

Tags: delphi

Ищу алгоритм, который с высокой точностью скажет есть инет или нет

```
(function HIC(): boolean)
```

Хорошо бы, чтобы данный метод был кроссплатформенный и показывал реальное состояние дел с инетом (а не как через WinAPI, когда статус меняется после отращивания бороды)

Также данная функция должна без проблем вызываться из потоков...
И желательно без Synapse....

P.S. У меня Delphi XE 10.2.3

Comment: А что вы уже сделали, чтобы найти такой "алгоритм"? Ваш вопрос выглядит как задание для фрилансера. Здесь на такие вопросы отвечать не принято. Это не фриланс биржа. Посетители этого ресурса **безвозмездно помогают** решить проблемы тем, кто хочет **решить их самостоятельно**.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "есть инет"? Вот устройство подключено к wi-fi сети. Это есть инет или нет? А если wi-fi дает только локалку? Если вам нужен конкретный сайт - попробуйте обратиться к нему. THTTPClient в помощь."А не как через WinAPI" - что угодно кросс-платформенное, будучи запущено под управлением операционной системы, будет работать через и только через API этой OC

Comment: Мне нужна проверка реального наличия интернета (это не фриланс, а разработка проги для скачивания Dr.Web CureiT, можете загуглить - DWAKU (я выкладываю ее в открытый доступ)

Comment: Дeлал через TidHTTP и попытка скачивания ya.ru

Comment: НО! данный модуль даже в потоке писылает сообщения об ошибке и кучу ошибок при нормальном инете

Comment: Я понимаю, что совсем без WinAPI не обойтись, я просто прошу без Windows в uses - у 10.2.3 баг с утечкой памяти в данном модуле

Comment: Ну так пинганите сервер, с которого вы собираетесь что-то  скачивать. В INDY компонентах есть пингатор.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже выше написал - компоненты INDY  из потока плохо работают - поэтому и задал вопрос м(Плохо работают в плане вылета ошибок)

Comment: `Мне нужна проверка реального наличия интернета` да поймите вы,нет такого понятия как "наличие интернета". Можно проверить только *доступность определенного ресурса в сети для своего процесса*. И тут много факторов, включая черный список РосКомНадзора или локальное запрещение файрволлом. Если вам нужно скачать CureIt - так и обращайтесь http GET (HEAD)-запросом к необходимому ресурсу. По http-коду ответа поймёте, есть доступ для вашего приложения к нужному ресурсу или нет. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient

Comment: Например, "реальный интернет" у меня на компьютере есть. Но я запретил вашему приложению куда-либо лезть через файрволл. Браузеры, торренты и всё подряд работает, а ваше приложение - нет. И какой смысл в "реальном наличии интернета", если вы не имеете к нему доступа?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: `компоненты INDY из потока плохо работают` - извините, но это *бред сивой кобылы*. При правильном использовании, Indy работает просто замечательно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, "реальный интернет" у меня на компьютере есть. Но я запретил вашему приложению куда-либо лезть через файрволл. Браузеры, торренты и всё подряд работает, а ваше приложение - нет. И какой смысл в "реальном наличии интернета", если вы не имеете к нему доступа?

Нет такого понятия как "наличие интернета". Можно проверить только доступность определенного ресурса в сети для своего процесса. И тут много факторов, включая черный список РосКомНадзора или локальное запрещение файрволлом. Если вам нужно скачать CureIt - так и обращайтесь http GET (HEAD)-запросом к необходимому ресурсу. По http-коду ответа поймёте, есть доступ для вашего приложения к нужному ресурсу или нет.